# Tips of how to programming using cocos2d-x on Eclipse for Android

Tags: android, eclipse, cocos2d-x

I'm starting developing with cocos2d-x for Android phones.
I have followed these two tutorials to integrate the source codes for the Hello World game, and be able to debug (Java and C++ codes) on Eclipse.

http://blog.plicatibu.com/developing-with-cocos2d-x-for-android-on-linux/
http://blog.plicatibu.com/how-to-debug-cocos2d-x-and-java-code-using-eclipse/

It's all working well, I can run/debug both codes, but I don't know how to start programming.

There's a helloworld folder inside jni and it have a main.cpp.
Should I create my game classes inside the helloworld folder? Because I've noticed that all the source files (.h and .cpp) are outside the eclipse project (on the Classes folder). So I wanna know if someone more experienced can help me to start.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved it!
After following the tutorials, I went in the project properties then C/C++ General->Paths and Symbols, in the Source location tab, I've added the Classes folder auto generated by the cocos2d-x script to create a new project.
And to solve a problem with macros, in Eclipse Preferences, C/C++ -> Indexer, I just checked Index source and header files opened in editor, and now it works like a charm ;)

Answer (score 2):

1. You can code in HelloWorld, and then copy your HelloWorld.h and .cpp to cocos2d-x/android`s folder instead of the old one.

2.Also you can modify the **AppDelegate.cpp**. In this class you can find **CCScene *pScene = HelloWorld::xxxx();** change it to your Root Class Function.

I hope it can help you

Comment: Thank you Ree, but how can I change the AppDelegate class? Its folder appears in Eclipse like an include folder, not as source, so I can debug this code but Eclipse don't help me with the autocomplete. Do you know how I add this folder (external to the project) as a source folder?

Answer (score 1):

Go to:
project properties
C/C++ General *
Paths and Symbols -> Link Folder -> mark Link to folder in the file system -> browse (and select Classe from your project)

*if C/C++ General don't apper:
 go in file new C/C++ and select C/C++ project(Adds C/C++ Nature) Next
 Mark your project
 In project type (below) select Makefile project
 In Toolchains select --Other Toolchain--
 Finish